# Read huge .txt file with python

Tags: python

I have a problem in reading a huge txt file with python. I should read all the ~500M lines of a 33 GB .txt file, one by one, but for some obscure reason, my script stops at the 7446633rd line, and gives no error..
The script is the following easy one:

```
file = open ("file.txt","r")
i = 0
for line in file:
    i = i + 1
print i
file.close()
```

I tried the script on more than one machine, and with both 32 and 64-bit versions of python, but no luck..

Anyone knows what could be the problem??

Comment: Are you sure there are more than 7446633 lines ? (On linux you can get the number of lines with this `wc -l file.txt` )

Comment: Yes, sure, there are 360213059 lines, tried with that command

Comment: What error does the script exactly throws?

Comment: The problem is that the script finishes its running without any error..

Comment: How about `if not i %100: print(i)`?  The idea is that you are differentiating whether it's the file reading that is causing the problemOr perhaps printing "too much" to console.   The code above will print every 100th line count.  You could also try to redirect stdout to a file and see if that makes a difference.  I once had a Python program that would repeatedly crash, without warning, on the same line of a given input file.  It had run fine on dozens of bigger previous files.  Never solved it, just reorganized the code, and it's the only time I ever saw this type of behavior.

Comment: It could also be something specific to that line.  Could you swap the file contents around (big, I know) and see if it crashes elsewhere?  Like, move the top half of the file to the end instead (however that can be done).

Comment: Well, actually the code I used was the one you see now, it printed the counter only at the end of the iteration, I wrote it wrong here, sorry..

Answer (score -2):

Try using the "with" statement.

```
with open("file.txt") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        process_line(line)
```

Also you could probably think about processing the lines in parallel using celery or something similar.

Later edit: if that doesn't work try to open the files and then use a range to read lines (read in batches).

Comment: Just tried also with your version of code but it gives the same result..
To read lines in blocks I should know the length of each line, to use the seek function..